# How do I freeze rotation of a Rigidbody programatically?

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am creating a 2D platformer game, and I already wrote the script that moves the sprite forwards and backwards successfully. However, I am **extremely** new to Unity and C#, so I have no idea how to freeze rotation of the sprite.

I tried to do it programatically (because the use gravity option did not appear in inspector) like so-

```
void Update () {

    anim.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));

    rb2d.freezeRotation.freezeRotation = true;

}
```

but it obviously doesn't work. **How do I correctly freeze rotation of the sprite with c#? Where do I put this code?**

Thanks in advance-
George :)

Comment: Thanks guys! I tried both of your suggestions, and I got it to work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to constraint the rotation on one axis of your object is:

- Create a variable `float freezeRotationX = 5.0f; //5.0 is just an example`
- And write this `transfrom.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(freezeRotationX, transfrom.rotation.y, transfrom.rotation.z);` This line should be in the Update methode.

This will fix the rotation on the X axis and leave the other ones with their current value.
Of course you can create a variable for each axis.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you really don't have to use C#, you can just set the angular velocity of a `rigidbody2D` really high, but if that doesn't work, try constantly setting the transforms rotations to 0, (the code would look like this in the update function,

```
getcomponent<yourgameobject>().transform.rotation.z = 0
getcomponent<yourgameobject>().transform.rotation.x = 0
getcomponent<yourgameobject>().transform.rotation.y = 0
```

the syntax probably isn't correct, and it might slow down the game, but if your beginning unity it is a simple solution.